# Websocket connection refused. WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:2000/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, ratchet

I have used websocket: https://github.com/kishor10d/CodeIgniter-Ratchet-Websocket

I have implemented websocket on a site. It is working great on localhost but when I uploaded files, it doesn't work. First there was confusion regarding the port I am using which is 2000. Now after contacting Inmotion's support they told me that 2000 is live and there are no firewall issues. 
But I get this error when I reload the page:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:2000/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

According to their support there is no service listing to this port.

I have used CodeIgniter, Javascript

Answer (score 0):

If you're calling the localhost (127.0.0.1) from the client app, you're calling your own computer, once you have the backend running on a remote server, you have to use the server's domain name or IP address - I'd suppose your web/server hosting service (Inmotion) assigned you the latter.

Comment: it gave me error of connection timeout. their support asked me to use this IP 127.0.0.1

Comment: Anyways, if client side (browser app) is to use a connection to a server, it needs to have it's address, not localhost.

Comment: I have tried it with domain name & IP but it doesn't work. Can you please tell me what could be the issue?

Comment: Thank you guys ! This was an issue from the hosting i asked them to open my port they did, but firewall was blocking the port. It is now fixed